# Why don't 私 and 朝飯 go together?

Tags: word-choice

Earlier, I asked [a question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-as-time-particles-whats-the-difference) with the following examples:

> **私**は**朝飯**のみに茶を飲む
>   **私**は**朝飯**のみで茶を飲む

I was told in [a comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/17760/%E3%81%AB-%E3%81%A7-as-time-particles-whats-the-difference#comment40809_17760) that 私 and 朝飯 sound funny together.  Why is that so?

Comment: It seems to be a [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_%28sociolinguistics%29) thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word 「[朝飯]{あさめし}」, to begin with, is NOT your most generic word for "breakfast".  That word would be 「[朝]{あさ}ご[飯]{はん}」, or more formally,「[朝食]{ちょうしょく}」.  This means that it would take a certain group of people and/or certain situations for you to hear the word 朝飯 in natural settings among us native speakers.

Who would say 朝飯, then?  First and foremost, it is male speakers.  Any male speakers?  No, it would generally be the "tough guy" types.  Once in a while, however, even the non-tough guy would use the word if he were surrounded by other guys he knew very well --- call it peer pressure.

However, the next question is even more important.  How many of those tough guys with their own word choices would refer to themselves with the not-so-informal pronoun 「私」 when we have a few other choices that would go better and more naturally with a word like 朝飯?  This is why I said it sounded funny.  I just could not picture a guy using those two words in a short sentence in the real Japanese-speaking world.

I am not sure how you are reading 「私」, but the combination of わたし and 朝飯 would already be very rare and that of わたくし and 朝飯 would be near impossible.

Comment: I thought 朝飯 was readあさはん and was just a  short version of 朝ご飯.  Thx for the clarification.

Comment: @Daniel You should think of ごはん as a single word with the ご "built-in".

Comment: I hear 朝飯 and 晩飯 used a bit in Tohoku, mostly by older men who have no pretense of "toughness". The men I know who say it very often use 私 as a personal pronoun, too. I know that you said it's "generally" used by "tough guy" types, but I thought I'd add my two cents.