で Means of action and does it apply to states of being as well?
よかったぁ！ お祝いで 今日はごちそうなんだから！！
With this sentence I wonder would this mean something similar to ''Because we'll be having a feast today as a celebration'' considering that 男の子で東京に行く Can mean ''Will go to Tokyo as a boy'' ?
I'm merely asking as it seems both で and に can mean ''as'' in certain contexts. So how do you distinguish between those and when and why can で mean ''as'' a state of something?

What do you mean by "go to Tokyo as a boy"? Is this about a person who can freely change their gender every day? If such a context has been already set up, 男の子で東京に行く might make sense, but otherwise it's a puzzling sentence.

it seems both で and に can mean "as" in certain contexts. So how do you distinguish between those


に is a role marker. If your "as" means "serving as" or "functioning as", you can use に.

お土産に絵葉書を買う
to buy a postcard as a souvenir
お礼に手紙を送る
to present flowers as a token of gratitude
仕上げにパセリを乗せる
to add parsley as a finishing touch


で is a condition/scope/reason/method marker, and it corresponds to various English prepositions ("in", "at", "by", "with", ...) depending on the situation. You cannot expect one-to-one correspondence with English prepositions at all, so you need to remember the correct usage individually. See this: Does で in this sentence 「日本の昔話は代表的なものだけで、２，３百はあります。」 mean that the noun before it is a tool for the proceding sentence?


Provided that this person has the special ability to change gender, 男の子で東京に行く makes sense (it describes their state when going to Tokyo), but 男の子に東京に行く makes no sense ("serving as a boy" means nothing here).
Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/17763/5010

Alright I was originally confused because a grammar guide which I can't remember where from said this sentence ''観光で京都に来た'' Means ''Came to Kyoto as a tourist'' and got the impression with the de particle it could be used for state of being for certain nouns

Ah I now see, so as you said ''method marker'' so in a sense you are using yourself as a tool or a way of an action I assume with the で? so since as you said the 男の子で is weird and unnatural due to the weird changing behavior then would 走り屋で峠に来た make more sense since you technically can change into a ''street racer'' by practice ?

@DisplayNameOfWhat If you want to explicitly say "as a [role/job]", use として. You have to say either "観光で京都に来た" or "観光客として京都に来た".
